# WebApi method is not getting posted data. What is missing?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement the infamous `Todo` application using ASP.NET WebApi 2.

Todo model:

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

WebApi Post:

```
public void Post([FromBody]Todo todo)
 {   
     // code to handle post.
 }
```

`Javascript` click

```
$("#add").click(function(e) {               
      var todo = {
      "Id": 20000,
      "Title": "Hello world"                    
   };
   $.post( "http://localhost:51386/api/todo", JSON.stringify(todo))
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
   });              
});
```

My `HTTP` request body looks like this:

```
{"Id":20000,"Title":"Hello world"}
```

Using the default route.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I debug the method `Post`, it's always null. What exactly am I missing?

Comment: check if your request has `Content-Type` header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can think of based on your sample code is that you are not include the JSON Formatter in your configuration. It should be something like :

```
    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

The `Content-Type=application/json` only will work if you set the proper formatter.